# Regex to accept first and last name with a space but no special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

So I'm trying to come up with regex to accept first and last name, but the first and last name is mandatory.
Special characters are not allowed except - and , and . and '
I would also like to make the first and last name min length 2 chars each.

Some examples.
Invalid - firstname

Invalid - lastname

Invalid - f lastname

Invalid - firstname l

Valid - firstname lastname

Valid - f-name lastname

Valid - fname l'name

I have this regex
`(.*)([A-Za-z ,.'-]){2} ([A-Za-z ,.'-]){2}(.*)` which seems to work for everything except excluding the other special characters like !@ etc.
I think the issue is because we must match min length for first and  last name, with acceptable characters like in above regex.
But by excluding other special characters, it essentially reverses the logic.

Here is my [regexr](https://regexr.com/5g051)

> UPDATE for those interested I used two regex matches to get around this issue.
> The second regex is for more than one of the allowed special characters.

```
var match = nameVal.match(/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z,.'-]+ +[A-Za-z][A-Za-z,.'-]+$/gm);
var match2 = nameVal.match(/([.,\-']{2})/g);
```

Thanks @tshiono for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
^[A-Za-z,.'-]{2,} +[A-Za-z,.'-]{2,}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/q2XXuG/1)

If you want first and last name *not* to start with special characters, please try instead:

```
^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z,.'-]+ +[A-Za-z][A-Za-z,.'-]+$
```

**[UPDATE]**
As for the forked requirement not to repeat the special character, how about:

```
^(?:(?:[A-Za-z]|([,.'-]))(?!(?:.*?\1))){2,} +(?:(?:[A-Za-z]|([,.'-]))(?!(?:.*?\2))){2,}$
```

[Demo2](https://regex101.com/r/oe8Wbx/1)

Comment: Hi tshiono, that doesn't seem to work :( please check my regexr link https://regexr.com/5g2ou

Comment: Ok I needed to reverse the logic in my validation, seems to be working a treat. Many thanks :)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Please try to check the multiline flag.

Comment: Hi tshiono, I made a fork where the regex fail, can we limit allowed special characters to one only?
https://regex101.com/r/MWfoBC/1

Comment: Interesting question! I'll try to figure out the regex but it may be
obscured. From maintainability point of view, it will be better to
count the occurrence of special characters in a separate code
although it may not be an elegant solution.

Comment: Thanks tshiono, I did think of limiting them with javascript but I agree not ideal. I think regex is much better

Comment: I've updated my answer with the regex which will support the forked requirement. I hope it is what you want. BR.

Comment: Thanks tshiono, but now my match var returns null for both valid and invalid ```var match = nameVal.match(/^(?:(?:[A-Za-z]|([,.'-]))(?!(?:.*?\1))){2,} +(?:(?:[A-Za-z]|([,.'-]))(?!(?:.*?\2))){2,}$/gm);``` I tried with multiline and without. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, I should have cafefully tested my regex with JavaScript. It seems the regex support on JavaScript is not fully compatible with PCRE. Please let me consider again. We may need to choose another option (such as counting the occurrence of special characters) in some cases. BR.

Comment: I am sorry to say I can't find out the JS compatible regex at the moment. Please consider the possibility of "Plan B". BR.

Comment: Thanks tshiono I done two regex matches, seems to have done the trick